# Gstreamer rtsp camera delay

Tags: linux, gstreamer, pygtk, h.264, rtsp

i'm setting up a GStreamer pipeline to view some camera streams (rtsp) in a pygtk3 window. So far everything works fine, but I'm fighting with a delay of about 600ms which i don't know where to search.

I've got a gbit Ethernet connection between my camera and my Linux Computer nothing else. The Ethernet workload is about 400kb, my CPU is at about 13% load and i got 2.5Gb of free memory. So i don't think it's a performance problem.
The stream I use is h264 rtsp.
I'm testing with 3 different cameras and i also tested on an raspberry pi 3, but i always got a delay of about 600ms.

This is the pipeline I'm actually using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc latency=0 location=rtsp://192.168.1.35 ! rtph264depay ! fluh264dec ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

Thank you for your help.

Stephan

Comment: Did you try to add `queue` elements between elements of your pipeline?
-> `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc latency=0 location=rtsp://192.168.1.35 ! rtph264depay ! queue ! fluh264dec ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=false`

Comment: When testing with a Raspberry Pi 3 (for emission?), which video pipeline did you use?